# Why does "בני ישראל" sometimes include גרים and sometimes not?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, midrash, tosfot

*Tosafos* (to [*Suka* 28](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1153&size=1), [*Sanhedrin* 86](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=3781&size=1), and [*M'nachos* 61](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=4511&size=1); and *Tos'fos Harosh* to *Sanhedrin* 86) cite various verses containing the words "בני ישראל", *b'ne Yisrael*. In some cases, they note, the *g'mara* seeks an additional *d'rasha* to include converts into the *halacha* that the verse assigns explicitly to *b'ne Yisrael*. In others, the *g'mara* does not seek any such additional *d'rasha*. They ask this as a contradiction: if such a *d'rasha* is necessary, why is it not necessary everywhere?

They reply (in all three places, as do the *Tos'fos Harosh* in *Sanhedrin*) that "maybe" there is some such *d'rasha* that the *g'mara* does not mention.

Does anyone (1) know of a stronger version of that answer, one that either (a) explains why such a *d'rasha* would be mentioned explicitly in some cases and not in others or (b) lists such *d'rashos* that the *g'mara* does not, or at the very least (c) claims the existence of such *d'rashos* without qualifying that claim with "maybe"; or (2) know of another answer to *Tosafos*' question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Malbim (to Lev. 4:2, sec. 191)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37625&pgnum=109) argues for your option 1c: there are derashos in Sifra for all three of the cases that Tosafos mentions - being a zav/zavah, pledging erachin and performing semichah - that converts are included.

He explains at some length that indeed "bnei Yisrael" includes only born Jews. So mitzvos fall into several categories:

1. Those where it doesn't say anything about "bnei Yisrael." Those indeed apply equally to all Jews, by inference from the statement, "One Torah shall be for the native-born and for the convert" (Ex. 12:49).
2. Those where it says "bnei Yisrael," and there is an explicit or inferred statement that includes converts.
3. Those where there is no such statement, and indeed converts are excluded.